# Cached Process.Threads instead of live value

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I'm having trouble accessing Threads of a `Process`-Object.

It seems like `System.Diagnostics.Process.Threads` is a cached array instead of being read upon access. This means, that retrieving the Process of another application, storing it during the lifecycle of your application and accessing its Threads periodically will not yield the expected output.

An example which shows, that new Threads are not added to that list. The other (unmanaged) process spawns Threads during this loop:

```
var cachedProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("application").FirstOrDefault();
Thread.Sleep(5000); 
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cached Thread Count: " + cachedProcess.Threads.Count);

    var liveReadProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("application").FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("Live Thread Count: " + liveReadProcess.Threads.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

The output is:

```
Cached Thread Count: 3
Live Thread Count: 3

Cached Thread Count: 3
Live Thread Count: 4

Cached Thread Count: 3
Live Thread Count: 5

Cached Thread Count: 3
Live Thread Count: 6

Cached Thread Count: 3
Live Thread Count: 7
```

I actually expected the access on `cachedProcess.Threads` being equal to `liveReadProcess.Threads`, but this is not the case.

Is there a way to cache the process-handle and have an updated Thread-List without accessing the WinAPI directly?

Comment: It seems that the answer is obviously no. Caching and live updating are conflicting options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to cache the process-handle and have an updated Thread-List without accessing the WinAPI directly?

The `Process` class won't update the cached thread information automatically. However, if you just call the `Process.Refresh()` method, you can force the update:

```
var cachedProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("application").FirstOrDefault();
Thread.Sleep(5000); 
while(true)
{
    cachedProcess.Refresh();
    Console.WriteLine("Cached Thread Count: " + cachedProcess.Threads.Count);

    var liveReadProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("application").FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("Live Thread Count: " + liveReadProcess.Threads.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```